# How can I combine a set of parameters like search to display the results on a separate column?

Tags: php, mysql, css, search, pagination

I'm currently creating a real estate's website, although I'm familiar with html, I could use some hints about using the php on the following:

1. How could I link a search form and dropdown menus on a left column to display the results on a right column.
2. How could I use the pagination in conjunction with the php script made to display the results.
3. How can I make the results appear in accordance with my css styles for the displayed results.

I've searched a ton of tutorials and got the most results on how to create a search engine but without css styling or dropdown menus. I've attached an image of my layout to make it easier to understand.

Any tips on where to start or basic logic behind the setup would be helpful.

*Image:* http://postimg.org/image/5j2naarh3/

**Html:**

```
    <div class="w-clearfix main">
    <div class="search">
      <div class="param">
        <div class="w-form">
          <form name="email-form" data-name="Email Form">
            <h2 class="h2">Find Properties</h2>
            <input class="w-input dropdown" type="text" placeholder="Type your keywords" name="search" data-name="search"></input>
            <select class="w-select dropdown" name="property-type" data-name="property-type">
              <option value="">Property Type</option>
              <option value="First">Apartment</option>
              <option value="Second">Villa</option>
              <option value="Third">Land-only</option>
              <option value="fourth">Commercial \ Office</option>
              <option value="fifth">Chateau \ Mansion</option>
              <option value="sixth">Country Home</option>
              <option value="seventh">Loft</option>
              <option value="eighth">Equestrian</option>
              <option value="nineth">Golf</option>
              <option value="tenth">Vineyard</option>
              <option value="eleventh">Other</option>
            </select>
            <select class="w-select dropdown" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">Choose Country</option>
              <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
              <option value="es">Spain</option>
            </select>
            <select class="w-select dropdown" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">Choose City</option>
              <option value="lx">Lisbon</option>
              <option value="st">Setubal</option>
              <option value="mt">Montemor</option>
            </select>
            <select class="w-select dropdown" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">Price Range</option>
              <option value="First">100.000 - 500.000 €</option>
              <option value="Second">500.000 - 1.000.000 €</option>
              <option value="Third">1.000.000 - 5.000.000 €</option>
            </select>
            <input class="w-button param_button" type="submit" value="Reset" data-wait="Please wait..."></input>
            <input class="w-button param_button _2" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait..."></input>
          </form>
          <div class="w-form-done">
            <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w-form-fail">
            <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form :(</p>
          </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="results">
      <div class="ind_result">
        <div class="w-row">
          <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-small-6 w-clearfix image">
            <img class="image" src="images/3.jpg" alt="3.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="w-col w-col-9 w-col-small-6 w-clearfix desc"><a class="title" href="#">Superb 5 room Apartment</a>
            <h4 class="price">990 000 €</h4>
            <h5 class="sub-title">Tróia - Setúbal</h5>
            <p class="description">BOULOGNE, facing the woods, superb five rooms apartment opening from both sides on two large private terraces (53 m²) apartment. In perfect condition, and very functional plan is ideal: entrance, living room, kitchen, three bedrooms (a fourth
              is possible), two bathrooms, two parking spaces and a cellar</p>
            <img class="map" src="images/show_on_map_btn.png" alt="show_on_map_btn.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little about your data structure?

Comment: Hi ALLInOne, already updated the html. that's pretty much what I have so far. thanks

Comment: You may want to look into Ajax if your wanting to dynamically load the search data, take a looke at: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Thanks Last1Here, I've read the article but my concern mostly is on how I could link the pagination to the divs that include the titles description and images. Most pagination tutorials only teach paginating single lines of text while I'm faced with having to load the images and the div blocks.

Comment: Hi Francisco, this post is tagged as MySQL so when I asked about data structure I was asking you to describe your MySQL data structure.  If you don't have one yet getting that together would be a good first question.  There should really only be one question per StackOverflow "question" yours lists three, and it seems like there are a few things to decide before you tackle those. It has been a couple of days now with no answers here, so I'd recommend you start again with one question.